# Spark Join based on nearest Date

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 parquet tables. The simplified schema is as follows:

```
case class Product(SerialNumber:Integer,
                   UniqueKey:String,
                   ValidityDate1:Date
                   )
                   
case class ExceptionEvents(SerialNumber:Integer,
                      ExceptionId:String,
                      ValidityDate2:Date
                     )
```

The Product Dataframe can contain the following entries, as an example:

**Product:**

```
-----------------------------------------
SerialNumber    UniqueKey   ValidityDate1
-----------------------------------------
10001           Key_1       01/10/2021
10001           Key_2       05/10/2021
10001           Key_3       10/10/2021
10002           Key_4       02/10/2021
10003           Key_5       07/10/2021
-----------------------------------------
```

**ExceptionEvents:**

```
-----------------------------------------
SerialNumber    ExceptionId     ValidityDate2
-----------------------------------------
10001           ExcId_1         02/10/2021
10001           ExcId_2         05/10/2021
10001           ExcId_3         07/10/2021
10001           ExcId_4         11/10/2021
10001           ExcId_5         15/10/2021
-----------------------------------------
```

I want to join the 2 DFs such that the SerialNumbers match and the ValidityDate shall be mapped such that ValidityDate2 of ExceptionEvent is greater than ValidityDate1 of Product, but the 2 dates should be as close as possible.
For example, the resultant DF should look like below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
SerialNumber    ExceptionId     UniqueKey       ValidityDate2
---------------------------------------------------------------------
10001           ExcId_1         Key_1           02/10/2021
10001           ExcId_2         Key_2           05/10/2021
10001           ExcId_3         Key_2           07/10/2021
10001           ExcId_4         Key_3           11/10/2021
10001           ExcId_5         Key_3           15/10/2021
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any idea how the query should be done using scala & spark Dataframe APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below solution works fine for me:

```
val dfp1 = List(("1001", "Key1", "01/10/2021"), ("1001", "Key2", "05/10/2021"), ("1001", "Key3", "10/10/2021"),  ("1002", "Key4", "02/10/2021")).toDF("SerialNumber", "UniqueKey", "Date1")

val dfProduct = dfp1.withColumn("Date1", to_date($"Date1","dd/MM/yyyy"))

val dfe1 = List(("1001", "ExcId1", "02/10/2021"), ("1001", "ExcId2", "05/10/2021"), ("1001", "ExcId3", "07/10/2021"),  ("1001", "ExcId4", "11/10/2021"),  ("1001", "ExcId5", "15/10/2021")).toDF("SerialNumber", "ExceptionId", "Date2")

val dfExceptions = dfe1.withColumn("Date2", to_date($"Date2","dd/MM/yyyy"))

val exceptionStat2 = dfExceptions.as("fact").join(dfProduct.as("dim"), Seq("SerialNumber")).select($"fact.*", $"dim.UniqueKey", datediff($"fact.Date2", $"dim.Date1").as("DiffDate")).where($"DiffDate" >= 0)

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val exceptionStat3 = exceptionStat2.withColumn("rank",  rank.over(Window.partitionBy($"SerialNumber", $"ExceptionId").orderBy($"DiffDate")) )
                        .where($"rank" === 1)
                        .select( $"SerialNumber", $"ExceptionId", $"UniqueKey", $"Date2", $"DiffDate", $"rank" )
                        .orderBy($"SerialNumber", $"Date2")
```